# Re-Rendering component, after click event in different component

Tags: reactjs

In my **App** I have a **HeaderLogo** component, with `<h1>` containing animation (inside its `head-main` class). I would like to re-render this component to trigger animation, after `onclick` event in `<NavLink>`.

`<NavLink>` is inside **DropdownMenu**, which is inside **MainNavi**.

**HeaderLogo**

```
const HeaderLogo = () => {

  return (
    <header>
        <h1 className="head-main">learning curve</h1>
    </header>
  )
}
export default HeaderLogo
```

**Dropdown Menu**

```
import { MenuItemContentSchool } from "./sub-components/MenuItemContentSchool"
import { useState } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";


const DropdownMenu2 = () => {

  const [click, setClick] = useState("");

  const handleClick = () => {
    setClick("hide-menu");
  }


  return (
    <div className={`dropdown-holder-us ${click}`}>
    {MenuItemContentSchool.map((item) => {
      return (
        <NavLink
            to={item.link} 
            className='d-content-us'
            onClick={handleClick}  
            key={item.title} 
        >
          {item.title}
        </NavLink>
      )
    } )}

</div>
  )
}
export default DropdownMenu2
```

**App**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import HeaderLogo from "./components/HeaderLogo";
import NaviMain from "./components/NaviMain";    

function App() {


  return (
    <Router>
        <div className="App">

          <HeaderLogo />
          <NaviMain  />

          <Routes>
              //...
          </Routes>
          
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**NaviMain**

```
import DropdownMenu2 from "./DropdownMenu2";

const NaviMain = () => {
       
  return (
    <nav>
        <ul className="nav-main">  
            <li className="nav-main__button">
                <a>school</a>
                <DropdownMenu2 /> 
            </li>           
        </ul>    
    </nav>
  )
}
export default NaviMain
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether this will work or not but u can try the following solution:

set an id:

```
<h1 id="testing" className="head-main">learning curve</h1>
```

Change

```
const handleClick = () => {
    setClick("hide-menu");
  }
```

to

```
const handleClick = () => {
    setClick("hide-menu");
    let element = document.getElementById('#testing').
    element.classList.remove("head-main");
    element.classList.add("head-main");
  }
```

Please let me know whether this solution works or not.

Comment: yeah, learning React I really miss vanilla JS simplicity :) I think my problem has to be solved using state, and "reactive" data. I will let you know.